# Left Outer Join Throws NULL Value in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hive, hiveql

I am getting null values if I use a left outer join even after mentioning `t.contractid=111111` in the `select` statement.  Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
select t.contractid,r.contractid,t.batchno
from tableA t 
left join tableB r 
on t.contractid=r.contractid and t.PayGrp=r.PayGrp and t.PriNo=r.PriNo 
where t.contractid=111111 and t.PayGrp=0 and t.batchno=201701 and t.prino=3
and r.contractid is null
```

Sample Output:

```
null    null    201701
null    null    201701
null    null    201701
null    null    201701
null    null    201701
```

Comment: you should say the structure of the table almost

Comment: Maybe you have r.contractid twice in your actual select statement?

Comment: please can you describe tableA and tableB columns

Comment: You try to check SELECT again. Are you using Select t.contractid or r.contractid?

Comment: I am using both t.contractid and r.contractid. My expectation is atleast I need to get 111111  value in the first column and second column it depends on the result

Comment: @Jos : can you provide table schema and some sample input ? I would like to give concrete answer based on that.

Comment: If this is hive related please confim by removing the irrelevant topics... it's just misleading for you as well as for those attempting to help you. If r.contractid = t.contractid **then t.contractid absolutely cannot be null using sql.** If you are using sql then the query and results provided probably do not relate to each other

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query and making assumptions based on the query the results your are reporting would be impossible which means something improbable is going on.

Why? It is not possible for `r.contractid is null`  and `r.contractid = t.contractid` and `t.contractid=111111` to all to evaluate to be true. Yet your query is asking the database that question and it is returning results.

The only way to explain the result is there is a custom data type for tableA.contractid and tableB.contractid in which comparing the data types results in a null value being equal to 111111. Similarly PayGrpt.PayGrp would require a datatype which comparing a null to 0 would evaluate to true. Of course, only looking at the data definitions of the tables could tell us this.

That being said I have experience weird results with columns matching in a join statement where one side or the other was null. So before considering the other possibilities, try wrapping your join and where conditions in  IsNull() this:

```
    select t.contractid, r.contractid, t.batchno
from tableA t left join
     tableB r 
     on IsNull(t.contractid,0) = IsNull(r.contractid,0) and
         IsNull(t.PayGrp,0) = IsNull(r.PayGrp,0) and
         IsNull(t.PriNo,0) = IsNull(r.PriNo, 0)
where IsNull(t.contractid,0) = 111111 and IsNull(t.PayGrp,0) = 0 and
      IsNull(t.batchno,0) = 201701 and IsNull(t.prino,0) = 3 and
      r.contractid is null;
```

Without the columns being some custom data type if the query above still produces the same result then you are dealing with some kind of system error, such as a corrupt database (or corrupt memory cache of that database) or even more unlikely a hardware error. First try rebooting the database server and the client machine performing the query (if they are not the same) and if the error still exists after a reboot try moving the data to a different database/db server and performing the same query. At that point you will know whether your have a corrupt database or are experiencing a system error on your database server.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am getting error while using isnull statement. org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 4:8 Arguments length mismatch '0': The operator 'IS NULL' only accepts 1 argument.

Comment: Sorry, you tagged your post `sql-server-2008`. Are you not using Microsoft SQL server. Why are you getting an apache error?

Comment: I am running this from Apache hive

Comment: Hence your problem. Apache hive is not `sql` or `sql-sever` or `sql-server-2008`. According to the docs you will need to use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL` which is a `MSSQL` operator see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: If I use this below statement still I am getting null valuesCOALESCE(t.idContract,0) = COALESCE(r.idContract,0)null null 201701
null null 201701
null null 201701
null null 201701

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  @AlexanderHiggins doesn't seem to know what an outer join does.

Answer (score -1):

This is your query:

```
select t.contractid, r.contractid, t.batchno
from tableA t left join
     tableB r 
     on t.contractid = r.contractid and
        t.PayGrp = r.PayGrp and
        t.PriNo = r.PriNo 
where t.contractid = 111111 and t.PayGrp = 0 and
      t.batchno = 201701 and t.prino = 3 and
      r.contractid is null;
```

The result set will always begin with `111111, NULL`, based on the `WHERE` clause.  `t.contractid` has to have a value.  Are you sure the table aliases are correct?  That the `where` clause is correct?

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @Jos . . . Based on the `where` clause, `t.contractid` cannot be `NULL` and `r.contractid` has to be `NULL`.  Is there any possibility that you are misinterpreting the results?

Comment: Even if I removed the r. Contractid is null condition  I am getting the same result

Comment: @Jos . . . The condition `where t.contractid = 111111 ` is pretty binding.  The `where` only has `and` operators, so this condition should be true on all rows in the result set.  `NULL` is clearly not `111111`, so your result set is confusing.

Comment: This answer is wrong because even though the condition is restricted to  It is not possible for `r.contractid is null`and r.contractid = t.contractid and t.contractid=111111 all evaluate to true. The query should return no results

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins . . . You clearly do not understand what a `left join` does.

Answer (score -1):

You are restricting your query by

> r.contractid is null

therefore it is ONLY returning NULL records - the result you are seeing is expected.

Comment: Even If I removed that r.contractid is null condition then I am getting null values on both the columns

Comment: I am viewing this result through Hortonwork Hive SQL Server.

Comment: This answer is wrong because even though the condition is restricted to `r.contractid is null` the condition `t.contractid=111111` combined with the join on `t.contractid = r.contractid` should result in no results being returned at all. It is not possible for 'r.contractid is null'  and `r.contractid = t.contractid` and `t.contractid=111111` all evaluating to true.